# Looking for Card Game With Streaks of Ashes on the Face

Tags: identify-this-game

I am looking for a specific Card Game that my Grandma and Grandpa both played when they were younger.

They don't remember the rules, but it appears that the defining feature was that, after a player would win a round, they would take some ash from a fireplace and make a streak on their face with it.

I don't remember what they said the name is, but I do remember that it is a semi-inappropriate word.

Any kind of info (name, rules, etc.) would help!

Thank you so much!

**Notes:**
It is not "Oh, Hell"

Comment: Was it played with a traditional deck of cards?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes.

Comment: I was thinking this was "Oh, Hell" but the ashes don't appear in any of the variants I could find.

Comment: What about "Oh Hell" makes that a reasonable guess? I wouldn't say that *players win a round* in that game.

Comment: Not necessarily win a round, but win a hand, etc.  I know it's not "Oh, Hell" because we also play that with them and they didn't say that that was the game.  I also remember that it had some other name.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 I thought that based solely on the description of what the questioner remembers of the name of the game (many families consider "hell" an inappropriate word for/around children).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a game that is known in dutch as black peeter (zwarte pieten), but it has [several names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_maid_(card_game)).

> In Greece the game is called "mu(n)tzuris" (μου(ν)τζούρης, "smudged, smutted"), because winners used to smudge the loser with soot.

The goal of the game was to remove matching pairs. Players moved one card to the player to the left, receiving one from the left. But there was one unmatched card. So the one left with this card lost and got ash or some other stuff that was black and hard to remove from their face.

Comment: Might be it.  The Wikipedia article mentions that one variant is called "jackass", which might be considered inappropriate for children in certain circles.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible they were playing a variant of a game commonly called ["Shithead."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shithead_(card_game))  This is a game that is conceptually similar to Uno, where the goal is to get rid of all one's cards, and variants often include special rules for various card values, such as reversing order of play, drawing extra cards, and so forth.

One core mechanic of the game is that the last person with a card remaining in their hand is designated the "shithead" and, at a minimum, has to deal the next hand, but variants often have the shithead paying some kind of forfeit -- fetching drinks for everyone at the table, or very possibly streaking ashes on his face.